# Sacar el registro repetido que tenga la fecha más antigua

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla enorme de registros. La tabla tiene varios elementos como Caja, Oficina, Cliente, DNI, Importe, Fecha... Cualquiera de esos datos se puede repetir. Hay varias cajas, varias oficinas, varios clientes e importes. Por ejemplo con la misma caja y dentro de ella dos oficinas distintas con varios clientes:

```
1 - 4276 - Alberto - 5€ - 2001
1 - 4276 - Alberto - 6€ - 2002
1 - 4276 - Alberto - 7€ - 2003
1 - 4276 - Alejandro - 23€ - 2010
1 - 4276 - Alejandro - 32€ - 2011
1 - 4276 - Alfonso - 70€ - 2017
1 - 5761 - Agustín - 655€ - 1996
1 - 5761 - Agustín - 100€ - 1999
```

Me gustaría sacar el campo que tiene el importe más antiguo, de todas las cajas y oficinas, es decir, las cajas y oficinas se tienen que repetir porque lo que me importa es cada cliente distinto:

```
1 - 4276 - Alberto - 5€
1 - 4276 - Alejandro - 23€
1 - 4276 - Alfonso - 70€
1 - 5761 - Agustín - 655€
```

Lo que ya tengo hecho (con una condición aparte que me piden de que el importe sea mayor que 50) es:

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, Cliente, Importe
FROM miTabla
WHERE Importe > 50
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente, Importe
ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente
```

Esto me saca de todas las cajas y todas las oficinas, todas las transacciones que ha hecho cada cliente, y sólo quiero la más antigua.

Comment: y... cual es el problema? si colocaste la solucion

Comment: perdon solo quite el `Importe `en el group by y te debe funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según tus requerimientos el query es bastante mas complejo, pero partamoslo en pedazos.

Primero, debes obtener los registros repetidos. Con eso alcanza hacer:

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, Cliente
FROM miTabla
WHERE Importe > 50
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente
ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente;
```

Ahora a eso, hay que agregarle el año. Como el año no es un valor que se repita, hay que agregarlo con una funcion y para obtener el menor de ellos nada mejor que la funcion MIN

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, Cliente, min(año)
FROM miTabla
WHERE Importe > 50
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente
ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente;
```

Y ahora el mayor problema de todos. El importe, no tiene una razon logica si no que queres el que corresponde a ese año, con esos datos de agrupamiento. Entonces para eso, no va a quedar otra que unir esta tabla "nueva" con la tabla vieja, y usar los campos iguales como condicion de join, y traer el importe que venga para cada caso.

```
SELECT 
    A.*, b.importe
FROM
    (SELECT Caja, Oficina, Cliente, min(año) as minaño
    FROM miTabla
    WHERE Importe > 50
    GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente
    ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente) AS A
    INNER JOIN miTabla AS B ON 
    A.Caja = B.Caja and
    A.Oficina = B.Oficina and
    A.Cliente = B.Cliente and
    A.minaño = año;
```

Si no hay ninguna repeticion en los campos claves (sobre todo el año) esto deberia traer un solo registro, con el importe correspondiente al menor año.

Comment: Si fuese la empresa más importante del mundo te contrataría. PERFECTISIMO. Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres el primero puedes agregar al final un LIMIT 1 solo para que te muestre el primero

ejemplo sencillo

```
select * from libros limit 1;
```

solo muestra el primero

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, Cliente, Importe
FROM miTabla
WHERE Importe > 50
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente, Importe
ORDER BY Caja, Oficina, Cliente
```

si esto te devuelve varios alberto agrega el LIMIT 1 al final solo te devuelve 1

Comment: Quiere el primero de cada grupo, eso solo le va a devolver el primero de todos.

Comment: Justo es eso, me da igual que se repitan las cajas o las oficinas, lo que no quiero es que se repitan los clientes

Comment: pero si eso le devuelve el primero de todo le sirve, segun lo que el indica.